# How to increase array size that has global pointer in each loop

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, realloc

I want to set the size of an array as the first integer in a text file (say 5). If I saved all the 5 integers that follow the size into the array, and there is still lines in the input file, I need to increase the size of the array each time and store that line (integer) in the array.
I wrote this code:

```
int *x;
int *sizeP;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int decision;
    FILE* file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
    int size;
    fscanf(file, "%d", &size);
    sizeP = &size;              
    x=malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    int p=0;
    int num;

    while(fscanf(file, "%d", &num) ) {
        x[p] = num;
        p++;
        if (p >= size) {
            puts("Enter 0 to continue or 1 to terminate");
            scanf("%d", &decision);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (decision == 0){
        while(fscanf(file, "%d", &num) ) {
            size++;
            x = (int*)realloc(x, size*sizeof(int));
            x[p] = num;
            p++;
        }
        free(x);
    }
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong with this code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `I am not sure what is wrong with this code?` Strange indentation, maybe?

Comment: What is the difference between what it should do and what it is doing?

Comment: If the first number in the file gives the size of the array, why would you need to allocate more space when you have reached the end of the file?

Comment: The first integer is the expected size, if there is more numbers I want the user to decide whether to accept the rest of the file or ignore it. The compiler stucks at the second while loop, then I get "Killed" in the command line output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way of checking the result of `fscanf` is not correct. When the end of file is reached, `fscanf` does not return 0, but `EOF`, which is not zero (it is defined as `-1` on most platforms).

> `while(fscanf(file, "%d", &num) )`

This will enter an infinite loop once the end of the file is reached, because since `EOF` is not zero, its boolean value is true.

The correct way to check the result of `fscanf` is to compare it with the number of fields expected. Since you are reading one value, you should the return like like this:

```
while(fscanf(file, "%d", &num) == 1) // <-- return value should be 1 on success
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This solved the problem of the infinite loop in the second while-loop. But still, when there is less values than the specified size, the first while-loop continues to receive all zeros.

Comment: @mera You should do this check for both loops. At the exit of the first loop you check also `if(p < size)`  then shrink the array (`realloc`) to size p, else check `decision`, etc..

Comment: The 'p' then would be equals to 'size', because it increases while looping. I don't know how to stop the first while-loop when there is no more lines in the file.

Comment: You stop it the same way as the second one:  `while(fscanf(file, "%d", &num)==1)`  ?

Comment: Well, I did the same but no the array is of size 'size' and reallocating it with 'p' size does nothing, I thought that is because 'p' is equals to 'size'.

Comment: Nevermind! Thank you for your help. It's working now! @A.S.H

Comment: @mera you are welcome, good continuation :)